# HTML file input naming when given a URL

Tags: html, input-type-file

We have a pretty standard file selector on our web page, defined like this:

```
<input type="file" multiple="" accept=".csv,.json,.zip,.jpg,.jpeg,.bmp,.png,.gif,image/*">
```

This works fine for selecting a local file, but we found that if the user pastes a URL in to the "file name" field, the browser (chrome and firefox tested) will download that URL to a temporary file and set the result of the file chooser to that temporary file.

It looks like the name of that temporary file is based only on the URL given; that is, a URL like `http://server/path/download?id=123` will result in a name of "download", while a URL like `http://server/path/123.jpg` will result in a name of "123.jpg", regardless of any headers defined on the response (e.g. `content-disposition`).

So my questions:

1. Is this behavior documented somewhere?  I couldn't find it in MDN.
2. Can this feature be disabled to only allow selection from the local file system?
3. Is there a way to control the file name other than the URL?

Comment: I don't know that this IS the answer you are looking for, but you could use `javascript` to validate the input to ensure it does not begin with http, https, etc

Comment: This [article](http://jkorpela.fi/forms/file.html) may interest you.. it looks fairly old, but covers some of the issue regarding your issue

Comment: We don't get the url back from the dialog, just the file, so we can't validate the input with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I think this behavior is actually coming from the operating system (windows 10), not the browser dialog, as I can reproduce the same behavior using other applications.  For example, in Eclipse I can paste URLs in the file open dialog, and they open in Eclipse with the same naming scheme.  I also tried on a few other OS's and, as expected, the dialog is provided by the OS so in some cases didn't even have a way to input a URL.